# Reboot Loop after logging from the block screen, Redmi Note 11

Tags: boot-loop, reboot, device-firmware, redmi, redmi-note-11

I have a problem but since I'm not an expert I need your help. I don't know if this is the right place but I'll try to reach for help anyway.

It's been 3 days since this smartphone (not mine) started behaving like this. I power it up, I type the PIN and after 15/20 seconds a little spinner starts rotating with a black screen in his back, shutting down the phone in 5 seconds (if I don't login with the PIN it doesn't shut down!! is this an indication that the problem is on the software side??). When I power it up, it goes in to the "main menu" where I got 4 options: reboot, wipe data, safe mode and MIassistence.
I would like to find a way to solve this issue without wiping the data.

What I tried:

- Deleting trash apps from the home page (my mom's fault, didn't know she played 20 games)
- Using the cleaner ( I got time to clean, but this didn't solve)
- Set the smartphone to developer mode -> set the usb connection type to: file transfer->
  wait for the reboot, plug the usb in pc, wait in blockscreen, wait... wait... Nope I got to type the PIN in order to access data! So I have to type it and the smartphone shuts down leaving me another time. When I go back I'm not able to access data because I have to login...
- Tried to log, put the smartphone on stand by, wait... it shuts down!
- Tried to update (now it's android 13.0.10, it says stable but there are available updates..) but obviously I got no time.
- Tried to go in Safe Mode, there is no "safe mode" label at the bottom-left and it feels the same as "normal mode"...
- Tried to massage the screen, front and behind (idk if the video suggesting this was a troll, I tried but probably he doesn't care about massages.)
- Tried to spam power button
- Tried to smash it on the ground, it works now! Thankk you guys for the attention :)
  No just kidding it does not work (and I did not smash it on the ground)
- Tried to find running processes, I was not able to find those.
- Tried to do a "security scan".. it gets to 6% and the smartphone shuts down (there is a payment environment issue anyway, and a green tick on the privacy & security, a spinner loading for the virus check, which I'll never be able to check since Redmi NOTE 11 shuts down!!!!).

I've also tried all of this without the sim card on, nothing changed.

I read this could be a firmware issue, but I'm not this much into android stuff, and I feel overwhelmed by all of these things.

Questions:

1. Anything else to try in this basic level
2. What could be the problem? (I'll try to look by myself but I don't have ideas on what to look for atm... I would like to know if having a way to update the firmware from pc would solve this.)
3. Is there a way to access data even though I'm not logged in?

Sorry for the ignorance on the topic, hope this doesn't resembles other questions on this forum, hope I'll get help, thank you for your time.